# Is it possible for a foreign employee to subscribe to a smartphone contract plan in Kazakhstan?

Tags: cellphones, kazakhstan

Is it possible for a foreign employee to subscribe to a smartphone contract plan in Kazakhstan? I might be teaching for two years in Almaty, so it's a basic need for me to get a phone.